# R/RShiny - Dropdown list is cutoff when not hovering

Tags: r, shiny, hover, dropdown

I made a dropdown list in rshiny, and it does work: I can see the list that I want. The problem is that I don't like how it looks when I go from hovering over the list to not hovering over the list. The list gets cutoff to the size of the dropdownbox (I guess). This is what it looks like:

[image: This is just hovering of the list]

And when I move the mouse just a little from the dropdown list, it shows a cutoff, eventhough the list is still selected (as it does show me the 2 first options):

[image: dropdown list cutoff]

This is my code:

**server.R**

```
function(input, output) {

 data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      return(NULL) }

    if (input$fileType_Input == 1) {
     tableRead<- read.csv(inFile$datapath,
               header = TRUE,
               sep = input$sep,
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
     return(tableRead)
    } else {
      file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                  paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=input$sep))
      read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=input$sep), 1)
    }

  })

 output$dropdown <- renderUI({
   req(data())
   selectInput('cols', 'Select Column', names(data()))
 })
}
```

**ui.R**

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Stap 1 - Upload excel",
             tabName = "stap1",
             menuSubItem(radioButtons(
               "fileType_Input",
               label = h6("Welk type upload file"),
               choices = list(".csv" = 1,
                              ".xlsx" = 2),
               selected = 1,
               inline = TRUE
             ),icon=NULL),
             menuSubItem(radioButtons(
               "sep", "Scheidingsteken kolommen",
               choices = c(`Komma (,)` = ",",
                           `Semicolon (;)` = ";",
                           Tab = "\t"),
               selected = ","
             ),icon=NULL),

             menuSubItem(
               fileInput('file1', 'Upload file', accept = c(".xlsx", ".csv")),
               icon=NULL)
             ),

    menuItem("Stap 2 - Kies juiste kolommen",
             tabName = "stap2",
             menuSubItem("Kies welke kolom waarbij hoort",icon=NULL
               ),
             uiOutput('dropdown')
             )
  ))


body <- dashboardBody(
)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

So maybe I can add something to

```
output$dropdown <- renderUI({
       req(data())
       selectInput('cols', 'Select Column', names(data()))
     })
```

or

```
uiOutput('dropdown')
```

But so far I haven't found a solution. What I would like to achieve is when someone clicks the dropdown it keeps the full dropdown, even when the mouse is not hovering. When the user either selects something from the list or clicks on the arrow of the dropdown, the list pulls in again.